# AngularJS - transition to login state if not having token

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanna redirect to login page if Auth.isAuthenticated() returns false after refreshing the page

```
.run(['Auth', '$state', function(Auth, $state) {
    if (!Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        $state.go('login');        
    }
}]);
```

And my `isAuthenticated` method in service Auth is returning true or false correctly

```
service.isAuthenticated = function() {
   var token = ApplicationStorage.getJwtToken();
   return token ? true : false;
};
```

But it's not workigng for me. Please suggest me that code redirect to login page if `isAuthenticated()` returns false

And 'ApplicationStorage' factory is like

```
 .factory('ApplicationStorage', ['store', 'APP_CONSTANTS', function(store, APP_CONSTANTS) {
var service = {};
/**
 * Store token in service variable when rememberMe is false
 * @type {String}
 */
service.token = '';
service.getJwtToken = function() {
    return this.token ? this.token : store.get(APP_CONSTANTS.JWT_TOKEN_KEY);
};

service.storeJwtToken = function(token, rememberMe) {
    // if remember me then store the token in local storage
    if (rememberMe) {
        store.set(APP_CONSTANTS.JWT_TOKEN_KEY, token);
    }
    this.token = token;
};

return service;
}])
```

Comment: How your ApplicationStorage.getJwtToken() function works?

Comment: `ApplicationStorage` is a factory. I edited & added in question patel

Comment: does `console` show any errors?

Comment: No console errors valverde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before, so you can definitely get it to work.

I recommend the [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) module in bower.  Rather than making your own 'ApplicationStorage' directly.  Less to debug.

If you want to do a redirect in AngularJS, inject `$location` into your controller and try this:

```
angular.module('app').factory('User', localStorageService) {

  return {
    getCurrentUser: function() {
      return localStorageService.get('currentUserId');
    },
    setCurrentUser: function(id) {
      localStorageService.set('currentUserId', id);
    }
 });
```

Then in your controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('SignInController', $location, function(User) {
  if (!User.getCurrentUser()) {
    // change the path
    $location.path('/loginForm');
  }
});
```

Something more or less like that.  It might not copy/paste/work

Comment: Ok Cole. I will store token in local storage using angular-local-storage. Suggest for redirection to login page if token not present in local storage

Comment: Yes Cole. Your solution is working for me. But why

    $state.go('login');

Not working for me

Comment: That's a good question I don't know the answer too.  I remember running into that and just using $location :-)

Comment: Your answer won't work. You didn't add `$location` in injection parameters. Just kidding. Happy to contact you.